# Import then export CSV PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have to export my result in an Excel table but everything goes in one cell. I would like to have a table with columns and rows.

The current excel file (Excel table):

```
Column1      Column2    Column3     Column4
infra-12    infra-88    infra-52    infra-55
infra-2     infra-3     infra-2     infra-12
infra-8     infra-71    infra-45    infra-71
infra-45    infra-2     infra-3     infra-52
infra-3     infra-27    infra-99    infra-2
```

Output without the export (in PowerShell ISE):

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4 
-------  -------  -------  ------- 
infra-12 infra-88 infra-52 infra-55
infra-2  infra-71 infra-99 infra-71
infra-8  infra-27          infra-52
infra-45                           
infra-3
```

Result when I export in an Excel table (this is in the table and everything is in one cell):

```
Column1,"Column2","Column3","Column4"
infra-12,"infra-88","infra-52","infra-55"
infra-2,"infra-71","infra-99","infra-71"
infra-8,"infra-27",,"infra-52"
infra-45,,,
infra-3,,,
```

Code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = [ordered]@{}
$columns = foreach ($i in 0..7) { ,[Collections.ArrayList]@() }

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $value = $row.Column1
    $ref[$value] = $true
    $columns[0].add($value) >$null
}

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $i = 1
    foreach ($col in 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4') {
        $value = $row.$col
        if (!$ref[$value]) {
            $columns[$i].add($value) >$null
        }
        $i++
    }
}

$maxLine = ($columns | select -expand Count | measure -Maximum).Maximum - 1
$csv = foreach ($i in 0..$maxLine) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Column1 = $columns[0][$i]
        Column2 = $columns[1][$i]
        Column3 = $columns[2][$i]
        Column4 = $columns[3][$i]
    }
}


$csv | Export-CSV -Path ".\test1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The code allows to remove the cells which are matching (same values) and display the others.

## EDIT

When I use the following delimiter:

$csv | Export-CSV -Path ".\test3.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","

```
Column1,"Column2","Column3","Column4"
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
```

With another delimiter:

```
 $csv | Export-CSV -Path ".\test1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"
```

```
"Column1    ""Column2"" ""Column3"" ""Column4"""
"infra-5    ""infra-7"" ""infra-9"" ""infra-2"""
"infra-1    ""infra-3"" ""infra-7"" "
"infra-4            "
"infra-8            "
```

I have to import the file in my script then export the output in a csv file, in this case an Excel table.

The expected result in the csv file (Excel table):

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4 
    infra-12 infra-88 infra-52 infra-55
    infra-2  infra-71 infra-99 infra-71
    infra-8  infra-27          infra-52
    infra-45                           
    infra-3
```

If needed, I can also convert the file extension into xlsx or xls.

Comment: If I go chronologically through all your questions I get the impression there is no advance in reaching your still nebulous objective despite all the help you got. Maybe you should commit your task to someone with more PowerShell experience. I'll end my fruitless efforts now.

Comment: I know but this is my first project in powershell and I want to get the base to be able to know what to do later, this forum helps me a lot to understand precisely what I need to do. I also help people with those posts if they have the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like you may be opening the file in Excel using a non-CSV format. On some locales the `,` is treated as a decimal separator and Excel will default to TSV loading of files there.

To work around this, you can use the [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) in the Data Tab to *Import From File*. This will allow you to select the delimiter that suits your needs (the `,`/comma in your case) and should work successfully.

Quoting from the documentation:

> ### Step 2 of 3 (Delimited data)
>
> **Delimiters**    Select the character that separates values in your text file. If the character is not listed, select the Other check box, and then type the character in the box that contains the cursor. These options are not available if your data type is Fixed width.

Comment: Don't know what do you mean. I need to use PowerShell to make that, there is no problems with Excel I've checked.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to encode in TSV format (if your recent edit's expected output is anything to go by). To accomplish that, you'll want to use the following:

`$csv | Export-CSV -Path ".\test1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "\`t"`

Comment: Sorry, nothing really changed except the commas have been removed. TSV would be a solution but a don't have the extension

Comment: I found the solution, just needed to include `;` in the pipe

Comment: Glad to hear you came right with it, do you mind perhaps updating your question with the answer in case someone else bumps into the same problem in future?

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected result mentioned I've used this:

```
$csv | Export-CSV -Path ".\test1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```